# Java - PDFBox - get text from PDF file

Tags: java, pdfbox

I want to get raw text from a PDF file.
I am doing that :

```
public String parsePDF (String fileNameorFilePath){
    File f = new File(fileNameorFilePath);
    String parsedText;
    PDFParser parser = null;
    try {
        parser = new PDFParser(new RandomAccessFile(f, "r"));
        parser.parse();
        COSDocument cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
        PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        PDDocument pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
        parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
        if (cosDoc != null) cosDoc.close();
        return parsedText;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

And I am getting this error :

```
java.io.IOException: Error : ~bfchar contains an unexpected operator : endcmap
```

at line

```
parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
```

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Do you get this error with all pdf files, or only specific ones?

Comment: *"java.io.IOException: Error : ~bfchar contains an unexpected operator : endcmap"* - that sounds like a broken **ToUnicode** map in a font in the PDF, a bfchar section missing its end marker, **endbfchar**. *"Is there a way to avoid this?"* - You can ask the document source to fix the PDF.